# Find elements that represent all sets

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, set

**How is the following problem called and which algorithms can solve it?**

*Setup:* I have a set of items (i.e. flags) each composed of a few unsorted elements (i.e. colours).

*Problem:* How can I find the minimal set of elements such that each item has at least one element in my minimal set? I.e. give me the fewest number of colours so that each flag has at least one colour in common with my minimal set.

This is similar or the same to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072942/algorithm-find-the-smallest-subset-of-cells-representing-all-the-rows) question, although (to me) the answer doesn't give a workable algorithm.

## Example

Let's assume we have three flags, and lets treat shades of colours as the same colour:

Bulgaria, Bahrain and Jamaica

[image: Bulgaria][image: Bahrain][image: Jamaica]

Possible solutions are:

- [White OR RED] and [Yellow, Black, OR Green]: Because both white and red are in Bulgaria and Bahrain and because Yellow, Black and green are in Jamaica.

Comment: Your solution made me think of [SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem). See the image under 3-satisfiability for example. I'm not sure you have such a tough problem though :p

Comment: "... the answer doesn't give an" - I think missed the end of that sentence. If you were going to say it's not satisfactory, the Set Cover problem is fairly well-known and it should be easy to find algorithms to solve it (but, it being NP-complete, finding the optimal solution to a reasonably-sized problem isn't viable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [minimum hitting set](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node149.html) problem, which is NP-complete. It is equivalent to the [Set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) (i.e. the two can be [converted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation) to each other).

Due to it being NP-complete, there is no known polynomial algorithm. Wikipedia gives a [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm) to get an approximate result. For an exact minimum you'll probably have to use an exponential time solution such as enumerating all possibilities.